# What's wrong with my Regex string for scraping link elements

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

I'm having a little problem with a VB.NET scraper, it's supposed to get all links of a html string, which I have already downloaded, and the links are there (I have checked), so it must be something with my regex string.

My regex string: `<a.*?href=""(.*?)"".*?>(.*?)</a>`

This works for some sites, but for others it does not.

Here are examples from the HTML source that match and don't match.

Working:

```
<a href="http://domain.com" rel="nofollow" onmousedown="return clk('25936','3')" target="_blank">/a>
```

Not working:

```
<a href='http://domain.com' target="_blank" ><font size=2><b>text</b></a>
```

Could it be because of the `"` and `'` ?

Comment: How are you using the regex? Why are there two double-quotes?

Comment: Well two quotes next to eachother means "

Comment: I am not sure how your regex matches the first example(What tool/language are you using?). You can try [this](https://regex101.com/r/xO1iQ0/1) out, to play around with your regexes.

Comment: *[he comes, he comes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1667004)*

Comment: @Kamehameha Sorry, this is vb.net

Comment: [`<a.*?href=(["'])(.*?)\1.*?>.*?<\/a>`](https://regex101.com/r/gM8cE1/1)

Comment: `Well two quotes next to eachother means "` yes, but you have `""` and in your sample HTML that will match nothing since you have content inside the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with following RegExp:

**`<a.*?href=[",'](.*?)[",'].*?><\/a>`**

You are using double quotes 2 times. since `a tag`'s href will be used with single and double quotes you have to check with both.

Comment: Thank you, it worked great!